# White cannot find OpenFileDialog

Tags: selenium, automation, openfiledialog, white-framework

Using Selenium, I've started Chrome and clicked a link that opens an OpenFileDialog but that's an OS level object and Selenium is now useless.
I'm brand new to White and I'm trying to automate this dialog but it cannot find it:

Here's my code so far(I know it's not much, I'm in the baby steps stage of White):

```
Application application = Application.Attach("chromedriver");
Window mainWindow = application.GetWindow("Open");
```

This gives me an exception:

```
Couldn't find window with title Open in process 21064, after waiting for 30 seconds
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478583/white-automation-framework-throws-an-exception-when-using-white-core-desktop-c/22891505#22891505

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<Window> modalWindows = mainWindow.ModalWindows();
Window openWindow = modalWindows[0];
```